# how to set up section heading so that it has one blank line before and no blank line after in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, line-spacing, vertical

With the memoir package, I can set up the section heading to have a blank line before with the command \setbeforesecskip{-1\onelineskip}. But how do I set it up to have no blank line after the section heading? I can use the command \setaftersecskip{.0001ex} to kind of get the right result.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeforesecskip{-1\onelineskip}%set a blank line before section heading.
\setaftersecskip{ .0001ex}%"kind of" set no blank line after section heading.

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question countering it self. You both want a blank line below the heading and not a blank line below the heading? What exactly do you want?

Comment: In addition, as always on this site: it us much much easier to help if you provide a full but minimal example

Comment: @daleif I thought the question is clear enough as is. I want a blank line *above* the heading, and *no* blank line *below* the heading.

Comment: Then use 1sp below. It just have to be explicitly larger than zero

Comment: Ok, thanks. What confused me was that this would seem to not place the following line exactly one line under the heading. I guess I don't quite understand the logic behind this, although I've been doing this intuitively.

Comment: Again your language is confusing. I'm reading "place the following line exactly one line under the heading" as there being a blank line under the heading. 1sp >0 means that there is a line break after the heading and a space of 1sp is added below the heading. It is about the wavelength of visible light.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've deleted that bit in the hope that this removes the confusion.

Comment: BTW: arguments to `\lipsum` should be in []'s, not {}'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 1sp as the space below. It just has to be strictly larger than zero. 1sp is super small.

For fun, here is a demo of where the baselines are (the tikz part needs a few compilations)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeforesecskip{-1\onelineskip}
\setaftersecskip{1sp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,opacity=0.5]
  \draw[red] ($(current page.west)+(0,2)$) coordinate (A) -- ++(10,0);
  \draw[red] ($(A)+(0,\onelineskip)$) coordinate (A) -- ++(10,0);
  \draw[red] ($(A)+(0,\onelineskip)$) coordinate (A) -- ++(10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```